# Activiti Clustering

Tags: activiti

I am pretty much new to Activiti.I have an specific question suppose I have 2 ativiti engines running on 2 instances and both shares common repository. Currently If I start any task on instance A and abrupt by making it down due to default nature of Activiti its is picked by B. which exactly I don't want to happen as two instances have different version of software running. I need below behaviour
"Job started on instance A should be finished by Activity A only if in case we pause it". Is is possible?

Many thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour of Activiti is that a job created on instance A will also be handled by instance A. Only in case the job needs to be retried, there is a chance that instance B will handle the job. To be sure that a job created on instance A will always be handled by instance A you need to extend the default job executor and set additional job handler config values. Before a job is executed you can check this config value to validate the job has been created on instance A.

Be aware that when you override the default job executor, in case instance A is down, the jobs for instance A will not be executed anymore. Maybe for your use case it makes more sense to use separate Activiti databases?

Comment: Thanks, Tijs for the prompt reply !!!
Can I get some reference/example for extending the default job executor for setting up additional job handler config values?

I was actually thinking in this direction of using separate Activiti Databases.